# How to return both an aggregate function result and a different column value from a query?

Tags: db2, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to build a select query that sums up value of a column and also get the fields from the column of the same table, and an example please . I am new to DB2 and still learning.

I tried using the below,

```
SELECT SUM(Column containing numbers)
      ,Column 2
FROM Table
```

but this gives me a SQL return code of -122

Comment: It seems this is not COBOL related, but SQL - you may want to switch those tags.
To be more clear: what is your table structure (only relevant fields), what data is in (three rows are enough) and what do you want to get as result?

Comment: Please add some sample data (in the form of `create table` and `insert` statements) and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the SUM [olap](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification) function.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(C1) OVER () AS C1_SUM
, C2
FROM 
(
          SELECT 1, 'A' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) T (C1, C2)
```

| C1_SUM | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2BItND5h)